# Socialite facebook add Instagram Graph instagram_basic and pages_show_list

Tags: facebook, laravel-socialite, instagram-graph-api

No, I am not trying to detonate a nuclear weapon, I am trying to use the Instagram Graph API. After jumping through hoops and getting it to work finally with personal account, I realize that I need to get the feed from a business account and that the whole process is even more complicated.

Anyway, using Laravel socialite package, I have the fb login working, but now I need to add instagram_basic and pages_show_list requests when logging in via fb login, where exactly do I do that? I tried in `FacebookProvider/scopes`

```
protected $scopes = ['email,instagram_basic,pages_show_list'];
```

But I get an error, I guess it goes somewhere else?

Comment: No, that looks like the correct place to ask for those permissions.

Comment: Yes, correct! It turns out the app has to be in "development" mode.

Answer (score 0):

then you are using laravel, so you need to do this:

```
Socialite::driver("facebook")->scopes(['email','instagram_basic','pages_show_list'])->redirect();
```

for more information, see the official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite#access-scopes